# Check if a string contains a value same as mentioned in a type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have below Priority type:

```
export type Priority = "low" | "medium" | "high"| undefined;
```

Below is my model which I need to submit but before that, I have to make sure that the value of priority is one of them else I throw a bad request.

```
export type CreateRecord = { 
 readonly priority?: string;
 readonly Name?: string;
};
```

Please I need your help on how to add this condition.

Comment: You are better off with an enum

Comment: if your priority can only have those string literals as valid prios, then why dont you use the type Priority instead of string and let typescript do the work for you?

Comment: Actually, the Priority type has already been created and is being used and I am trying to not create a duplicate code.

Comment: is this a runtime issue?

Comment: No, it's not @Estradiaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd use a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) for this rather than a union type:

```
export enum Priority {
    Low = "low",
    Medium = "medium",
    High = "high"
};

export type CreateRecord = { 
    readonly priority?: Priority;
    readonly Name?: string;
};
```

Usage example:

```
const c: CreateRecord = {
    priority: Priority.Low,
    Name: "foo"
};

console.log(c.priority); // "low"
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgO6oHSQJ4wKZwMYBOAljJADYCGAdgOZoD2htwAJg-nMODawEYMGAa2A5qAVwC2cNFEnkAxHEgk6AWjFS4AKG04AHjCaRQmyaAAKJJsSygA3ttDPQAGQbJQAXlAAich6+ADROLgCyOKzEUt5+kpHRksGhzgASxLTgsb7gGeC+2gC+ANy6BkaEJli4oADChDiUkDgASjj4TKyx9qApoA2U7NTkmKAw1iRYAPwIlhO2mKUu-Y1DI6AAcpTxM6DKqrSlJbod1Mqg+LP1jc1tHYRdPo7L48Q2WLNWb5OYaO7IIWWW3is18ADNBAVjtpTnAGOQcGgArQABT4NCvd6YACUxSAA)

---

Some folks are interpreting the question that you're receiving a string. That's fine, you can validate it and then assert it's a `Priority`. [The documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-runtime) talks about doing that, though somewhat incompletely. It's easiest if you make the `enum` names match the expected strings:

```
export enum Priority {
    low = "low",
    medium = "medium",
    high = "high"
};
```

then

```
function toPriority(x: string): Priority {
    if (x in Priority) {
        return x as Priority;
    }
    throw new Error(`'${x}' is not a valid Priority value`);
}
```

give you

```
const p = toPriority("low");
console.log(p);                 // "low", but with the Priority type
console.log(toPriority("foo")); // Runtime error
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABGAdgVwLYoApwCW8hCAnigN4BQKdKANjAO4oC8KARE85wDS162MABNCOdl2Fic-QXQAWhAOYLJnJas7UAvgG5q1UJFiJkKclDAoAwnDABDBGABKYAMbwRkyinkp7BxEYdAYKKCIScgB+AC58SKJyA3oAx2DQigA5B2E4lABnBCJ0ZQN9QwAzTHR3BGJ0CxgCYiSyAAoIeKKS5QBKeJaoihpUwkqUTpRCRqG2vqp-VPsETDhGiBQHAoTW0jIU+h1-BAU4FhR0MFYAUThzuHaAAwByABJKCB0X6Z30GAQWxQADcHAxCN45vsQWDMGAnn1yoZPOgiigoJIEM1Evt2twWJxEdQUQUYAwwAA6JjKdpQRGpBmMujAVD43h8FAAI0wgOYpDUp2sUPIFjIVmJIVJ5KpMBpWOFHU4lRgMEJ9JZKBcNXqwjQ93gQA)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is tu use an enum like :

```
 enum Priority {
  low = "low",
  medium = "medium",
  high = "high"
}
```

then you can use this enum :

```
export type CreateRecord = { 
 readonly priority?: Priority; // example
 readonly Name?: string;
};
```

Comment: string literal can be used in the same as enum. change to enum has no sense in this question problem solving